# How do I pass a custom attribute to a function?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

```
<select data-myattr="123" id="cboTest" 
        onchange="SayHello(this.data-myattr)">
```

This doesn't work. If I take the `data-`off of it it, it works, but from what I've read, it is html5 safe to do it that way. However, doing it that way, I get: **"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'myattr' is undefined"**.

This is my super-complex function:

```
function SayHello(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.dataset.myattr` (won't work in ["shitty" browsers](http://caniuse.com/dataset))

Comment: You probably meant *legacy browsers*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yea, that would be the appropriate term `:)`

Comment: They don't call them "shitty" in the biz? Hehe.

Comment: keep in mind that your `myattr` must be all lowercase. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9066

Comment: @Yatrix, sometimes we have to support them. Calling them names only lowers morale and doesn't achieve much, calling them legacy conveys more of a sense of positive, backwards compatibility effort instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It also makes the "legacy" browsers feel better about themselves, which is always nice...right before we kill them off in the holy name of progress.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<select data-myattr="123" id="cboTest" 
        onchange="SayHello(this.getAttribute('data-myattr'))">
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

> onchange="SayHello(this.data-myattr)">

Is being interpretted as `this.data` *minus* `myattr`.  You'd have to use:

```
onchange="SayHello(this.getAttribute('data-myattr'))"
```

instead.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It did for me in IE9.

Comment: Sorry, I guess DOM nodes don't implement indexers. Try using `getAttribute()` instead.

Comment: ...although the explanation of the encountered error is correct. Change it to getAttribute (and add why) and you'll get the +1

Comment: @Yatrix Hm, I tried my demo in IE9 and it didn't work (the alert said "undefined")

Comment: I just pasted it directly in VS 2010 and I was golden. I'm going with getAttribute anyway, since that seems to be the consensus.

Comment: @Yatrix - Yea, definitely go with `getAttribute`.  That should work in any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) should do

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/M4aXH/):

```
<select data-myattr="123" id="cboTest" 
onchange="SayHello(this.getAttribute('data-myattr'))">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Also, I'd try avoiding the use of inline scripts since they make HTML messy. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)/[`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (older IE) instead.

Comment: Why do you think hasAttribute was necessary?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I am creating the controls dynamically in a user control, so no one will see the html unless they view it in the browser. How would I go about using add/attach when I create controls dynamically in c# code-behind? I've never used them.